# Sort dictionary of dictionaries by value of lower-level

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am looking to sort a dictionary by the value of a 'lower-level'. For instance if i had the structure:

```
 salary_data = {"John D": {"wage":10000, "gender":male}, "Peter A":{"wage":12000, "gender":male}, "Emma":{"wage":5000, "gender":female}}
```

Then i want returned the keys of the initial dictionary sorted by the wage, in the second stage i.e. `["Emma", "John D", "Peter A"]`.

Comment: You are right ... was in process of editing question, but an answer to question now posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
print sorted(salary_data, key=lambda k:salary_data[k]['wage'])
```

Output:

> ['Emma', 'John D', 'Peter A']

[Demo](https://ideone.com/BJhNqG)